# MySQL connection from my desktop to remote MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, database-connection

The error specifically says "Host ..com is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server"

I have the correct userid and password which works fine on remote MySQL if I RDP and login locally.

The TCP port 3306 is not blocked as far as I am concerned. I used PortQry tool from my desktop and did "PortQry -n  -e 3306" and I got "LISTENING" response.

Comment: MySQL userids have a location ( ipaddress ) associated with them. Are you sure that the userid you are using is allowed to connect from your/any ipaddress. Its unlikely as its a bit of a security risk. When you RDP in and conect you are probably considered to be on localhost and therefore woudl be allowed in.

Comment: Oh ok that actually makes sense. I'm familiar with how SQL server works but this is the first time I'm having to connect to MySQL! Is there no way to do Integrated Windows Auth with MySQL? Thanks for the tip though, that should narrow down my investigation!

Answer (score 1):

Below is the excerpt from the mySql Docs

> If the following error occurs when you try to connect from a host
>   other than the one on which the MySQL server is running, it means that
>   there is no row in the user table with a Host value that matches the
>   client host:
>
> Host ... is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server You can fix
>   this by setting up an account for the combination of client host name
>   and user name that you are using when trying to connect.
>
> If the following error occurs when you try to connect from a host
>   other than the one on which the MySQL server is running, it means that
>   there is no row in the user table with a Host value that matches the
>   client host:
>
> Host ... is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server You can fix
>   this by setting up an account for the combination of client host name
>   and user name that you are using when trying to connect.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Great! thanks for your tip. RiggsFolly and you both seem to be saying the same thing. Do you know if MySQL supports IWA?

Comment: Yes we are suggesting the same thing. IWA can you expand that?

Comment: IWA = Integrated Windows Authentication. What is the best practice since there seems to be a few options? IWA is great as it makes single signon possible.

Comment: Yes that is possible, you can install a plugin from MySql called as The Windows Native Authentication Plugin but it is a commercial extention.